# gparted - Extend Root Parition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

i have the following partitions

```
dev/sda1 - 500 mb
unallocated - 181 gb 
/dev/sda4 - extended 23 gb 
/dev/sda5 - ext4 - / 15 gb
/dev/sda6 - linux-swap 7.6 gb 
/dev/sda4 - ntfs - 261 gb 
unallocated - 2.02 mb
```

I want to merge use 50 gb from the 181 gb and merge it with /dev/sda5 as my root parition is only 15 gb

Please advise how to achieve this

Comment: Please see my answer, and please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviated procedure...

## ps: you can't really have two sda4 partitions...

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

The use of an extended partition (sda4) makes this a little difficult. I'll outline the easiest way first, and we can add more to the procedure if we have to.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the left side of sda4 (extended partition) left 50gb
- **move** sda5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of sda5 all the way right

If it looks correct, hit the **Apply** button.